# Using macros on blackwidow ultimate

Tags: keyboard

So I need some help, is there any way to enable the m keys on a blackwidow ultimate in ubuntu, and if so How is it done ( Im new to ubuntu and none of the current answers posted here make much sense to me) Also, once enabled how do you assign them to a command?